# Is it possible to use comprehension expressions in custom directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

Is there a way to use a comprehension expression similar to what you'd use in `ng-options` to create a group of radio buttons or check boxes?

**app.js**

```
angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller("controller", ["$scope", function($scope){
        $scope.selectedRadio = null;
        $scope.selectedCheckboxes = [];
        $scope.radioOptions = [
                    //some options...
             ];
        $scope.checkboxOptions = [
                    //some options...
             ];
    }]);
```

**index.html**

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controller>
    <radio-group ng-radios="option as option.option_label
                            for option in radioOptions
                            track by option.option_id"
                 ng-model="selectedRadio"
                 ng-selected="option.selected" />
    <checkbox-group ng-checkboxes="option as option.option_label
                                   for option in checkboxOptions
                                   track by option.option_id"
                    ng-model="selectedCheckboxes"
                    ng-selected="option.selected"  />
</div>
```

I'm hoping to avoid using a complicated regex to support all forms of comprehension expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason because `ngOptions` (as well as e.g. `ngRepeat`) offers custom expression syntax is [because it was coded to support it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.2/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L250).

To support custom expressions in third-party directive the one should parse attribute values manually with regexps - borrowed from existing directives or written from scratch.

Apart from basic [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) supported by `$interpolate` and `$parse` services, there's no built-in expression magic in Angular.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to just make it myself. No two ways about it. I was just hoping that it was already out there.